No signals using library ieee_proposed using Newton-Raphson refinement
I use the ieee_proposed library and try to do a newton-raphson refinement. The code compiles and simulates, but I get no signals. It works with float32 in the library ieee.float_pkg.all.  But, I want float64 for better accuracy and then truncate it to float,32.  It doesn't work to open Data flow design, but it works to simulate the signal. Here is the code and the testbench:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library ieee_proposed;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee_proposed.math_utility_pkg.all;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;
use ieee_proposed.float_pkg.all;

entity rsqrt_refine is
    port (
        approx_in  : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- Approximation input (IEEE 754, 32 bits)
        input_in   : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- Original input value (IEEE 754, 32 bits)
        result_out : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)  -- Refined result (IEEE 754, 32 bits)
    );
end rsqrt_refine;

architecture Behavioral of rsqrt_refine is
    -- Constants for floating-point arithmetic in float64
    constant ONE_POINT_FIVE : float64 := to_float64("0011111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"); -- 1.5 as float64
    constant POINT_FIVE : float64 := to_float64("0011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");   -- 0.5 as float64

    -- Function to convert float64 to std_logic_vector as float32
    function float64_to_float32_slv(f: float64) return std_logic_vector is
        variable f32: float32;
    begin
        f32 := to_float32(f); -- Convert float64 to float32
        return std_logic_vector(f32); -- Convert float32 to std_logic_vector
    end function;

begin
    process(approx_in, input_in)
        variable input_val : float64;
        variable refined   : float64;
        variable temp      : float64;
        variable approx    : float64;
    begin
        -- Step 1: Convert inputs to float64
        approx := to_float64(UNRESOLVED_float(approx_in)); -- Convert std_logic_vector to float64
        input_val := to_float64(UNRESOLVED_float(input_in)); -- Convert std_logic_vector to float64

        -- Step 2: Perform one Newton-Raphson refinement using float64
        temp := subtract(ONE_POINT_FIVE, multiply(POINT_FIVE, multiply(input_val, multiply(approx, approx))));
        refined := multiply(approx, temp);

        -- Step 3: Convert refined result back to std_logic_vector as float32
        result_out <= float64_to_float32_slv(refined); -- Convert float64 to std_logic_vector (float32)
    end process;
end Behavioral;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity rsqrt_refine_tb is
end rsqrt_refine_tb;

architecture Behavioral of rsqrt_refine_tb is
    -- Testbench signals
    signal approx_in  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal input_in   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal result_out : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
    -- Instantiate the rsqrt_refine entity
    uut: entity work.rsqrt_refine
        port map (
            approx_in  => approx_in,
            input_in   => input_in,
            result_out => result_out
        );

    process
    begin
        -- Set test inputs
        -- approx_in = 0x5E800000 (1.875 in IEEE 754)
        approx_in <= "01011110001101010000010011110011";
        -- input_in = 0x01800000 (~1.19209e-7 in IEEE 754)
        input_in <= "00000010000000000000000000000001";

        -- Wait for computation
        wait for 10 ns;

        -- Observe result_out for the refined value
        wait;
    end process;
end Behavioral;



I had to several changes to have a valid input to to_float32(x).  I had to change it to to_float32 (UNRESOLVED_float(x)) to make the code compile.
